# How can I control the naming of elements in a scaffolded list editor in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following markup in an Edit view for my list of Sectors:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IndustryId, Model.IndustrySelectList)
<div id="sector-list">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.SectorList)
</div>
```

`Model.SectorList` is of type `DropDownItemListModel`. Then I have an `EditorFor` template for  `DropDownItemListModel` as follows:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Items[i])
}
```

Model binding for the list works if I pass `Model` to `EditorFor`, and each row in the scaffolded html has elements named `Items[0].Name` etc. However, when I pass `Model.SectorList` to `EditorFor`, I get row elements named `SectorList.Items[0].Id` etc. and these don't bind back to my model on post. How can I control how these are named?

Comment: On the controller action what type are you trying to bind?

Comment: @iaimtomisbehave, I am trying to bind to `SectorViewModel` which is the type of `Model` in the markup shown.

Comment: Your code looks fine it should be binding. Can you post the Model code? Also are you using any custom model binders?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `EditorFor` template to say:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i])
}
```

you may be able to get the naming conventions to match up as expected.